# How do I know that Developer Survey is ongoing?

Tags: discussion, survey

I have just received the "Developer Survey 2017 results are in" e-mail, I didn't however received any survey participation invitations on e-mail or global SE inbox, both in 2017 and in 2016.

Is it some bug or the survey intentionally filters users so that only avid and active ones receive the invitation?